# why a class is loaded when not in classpath?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, classloader

My app is started by some process (control-m). It's started from a bash script which I can modify (the script is invoked by the other process).

The app is being run with wrong version of spring. The thing is - I know which jar is being loaded, but it is not on the classpath! The classpath is provided in the bash script. I've also verified it by executing:

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
java.net.URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();
for(java.net.URL url: urls){
    System.out.println(url.getFile());
}
```

But still some jars are loded which should not be. I have -verbose:class in the command line. How can I find out why the clases I need are loaded from invalid jars? Why these jards are even being loaded? How to debug the classloading process?

When I run the script (instead of that other process) from my user account everything is fine.

Comment: Could there be something in the environment such as a CLASSPATH environment variable?

Comment: Also make sure you are using the same JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason. There was a jar on the classpath which had permissions set in a way that regular user did not have access to it, but control-m did. When run from my account it was ignoring this jar and everything was working ok.

But when run by control-m it was loading that jar, which additionally had "Class-Path" entry in the manifest and that was altering the class-loading process.